# What is the best way to have ruby gem locally but not pushing it to remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I'm curious if there is some comfortable way to use some gem locally but not pushing it to a public repository.
For example, let's assume that project I'm working on is not using in development gem like`better_errors`, but it may be very useful for me.
**I know I could add it to my Gemfile and just not include it in a commit, but then I could forget about it and push it someday. Also keeping it in mind all the time may be frustrating.**
I just wonder is there some nice way to have it automatically included in the local copy and preventing from pushing.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an initializer like this to your Rails app:

```
# in config/initializers/local_gems.rb
%q[better_errors binding_of_caller].each do |gem|
  require(gem) rescue puts("Gem not installed: #{gem}")
end
```

But this only loads the gem when it was installed before and that means you have to install it manually and cannot use bundler.